# How can I use Brightway2 with US LCI database?

Tags: brightway

#### **Short version:**

I am trying to upload US LCI database to Brightway2 and I am failing miserably. Has anyone succeeded? If so, could you share it with me? :D

#### **Long version:**

I am following the notebook [IO - Importing the US LCI database](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/IO%20-%20Importing%20the%20US%20LCI%20database.ipynb) notebook and I am having a lot of problems. I am aware that, as the notebook indicates, it is a work in progress. Anyhow, I wanted to give it a try:

I tried uploading every ecospold version database found [here](https://github.com/uslci-admin/uslci-content/blob/dev/docs/release_info/release-downloads.md), following the method from the notebook. The only one that gave me a similar results was version [FY20.Q3.02](https://github.com/uslci-admin/uslci-content/blob/dev/downloads/uslci_fy20_q3_02_olca1_10_3_ecospold.zip). However, right off the bat I get the following differences/errors:

1. Same as the notebook, I get this error: `Couldn't apply strategy link_technosphere_by_activity_hash: Object in source database can't be uniquely linked to target database.` And two activities that are linked. When I follow the instructions of ignoring these datasets, it throws me that error over and over again.
2. Trying to move on with the tutorial, I get more errors and at the end I end up with all exchanges unlinked:

```
633 datasets
37513 exchanges
37505 unlinked exchanges
```

3. Finally, after running the code in line [15]:

```
import functools
f = functools.partial(link_iterable_by_fields,
    other=Database(config.biosphere),
    kind='biosphere'
)
sp.apply_strategy(f)

sp.statistics(f)
```

I end up with:

```
0 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
```

Which is hilarious and sad at the same time. Since I am new with Python and BW, my troubleshooting is clumpsy and probably erroneous (I promise I googled a lot and went through the code). And concluded I am failing and it is time to ask questions:

Has anybody succeeded uploading the US LCI database to Brightway2?

If so, how? Which file did you use?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent question. I have added text to the offending notebook to note that it is obsolete.

In general, I think trying to import the ecospold files is a fools errand, as though they are labeled ecospold2, they are actually ecospold1 (which is a totally different format):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ecoSpold xmlns="http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold01">
```

The most recent export also raises an error when I try the ecospold1 importer:

```py
AttributeError: no such child: {http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold01}modellingAndValidation
```

This is a required attribute in ecospold1.

I think the best way forward would be to consume the JSON-LD directly. Note that it is important **not** to run `bw2setup()`, as you would also want to use their list of elementary flows and LCIA methods. Currently the [experimental JSON-LD importer](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/master/bw2io/importers/json_ld.py) fails because the provided datasets need allocation, but don't provide a set of consistent allocation methods. When I use the git checkout of `bw2io` and do the following:

```py
uslci = JSONLDImporter(
    "/Users/cmutel/Downloads/National_Renewable_Energy_Laboratory-USLCI_Database/", 
    "US LCI", 
    preferred_allocation="CAUSAL_ALLOCATION"
)
uslci.apply_strategies()
```

I get the following error:

```py
UnallocatableDataset: We currently only support exchange-specific CAUSAL_ALLOCATION
```

This is fixable, but someone would need to step through this and fix the allocation procedure, and I don't have the time to do that now.

Comment: Yes! I saw that that the data was wrongly labeled, that is why I used SingleOutputEcospold1Importer. Another thing I noticed is that all the "duplicated" (74!!) are actually the electricity flows. So I should not ignore these.
I am not using that data for commercial purposes. I want to US LCI is because I am working on an Open-Source python package that models different circularity pathways for photovoltaic modules.Looking forward for that JSON-LD importer. By the way, I am meeting with the USLCI dataset admins, so maybe I can shed some light on this matter soon :)

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to start importing using JSON-LD.